# How are the GUID values for AddIn extensions created?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, extensions

The AddInID GUID is straightforward, but when an extension is defined inside the AddIn,  it is also assigned a GUID value when it is enabled for the first time.

How (or where) is this GUID value obtained?

I've observed that it is the same across a couple of test machines.  Is this always the case?  If not, what would cause them to be different?

Example:

List of extensions before in the registry(`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.x\ArcMap\Extensions`) before enabling an extension on a freshly installed AddIn:
[image]

After the extension is enabled in the ArcMap Extensions dialog window:
[image]

The extension GUID `90814AD9-4737-553A-DF7F-E7039E4B3AF7` is now present in the extensions registry. This is not the same value as the AddIn ID.

I've searched the current user profile and the AddIn source code for this value with no results.  Where does it come from?